# Cakephp User type(group name) name not appending in Routing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.0 ACL with Auth components.
  My groups table contain 3 types admin, manager and user

I enabled the Routings in Core.php file

```
  Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin','manager','user'));
```

default.ctp file contains following line to link to products:

```
   $this -> Html -> link(__('Products'), array('controller' => 'products','action'  => index'));
```

when i logged in as admin the above link is http://www.example.com/admin/products/index
when i logged in as manager the above link is http://www.example.com/products/index
the group name "manager" is not appending before products

I need the following output when i logged in as manager

```
http://www.example.com/manager/products/index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line in the view:

```
$this->Html->link(__('Products'), array('controller' => 'products','action'  => index','manager'=>true));
```

As in, adding `'manager'=>true` to the list of options passed to the `HtmlHelper::link()` method, or whichever prefix name you need in the URL (i.e. admin, manager...).

To work out which prefix is currently used, you can use this snippet:

```
$opts = Router::parse(Router::url(''));
$prefix = $opts['prefix']; // Contains 'admin' or 'manager', etc.
```

You can then pass `$prefix=>true` as an option the Html link method.

Comment: If i give manager => TRUE and while I logged in as ADMIN the URL is http://www.example.com/manager/products/index .

Comment: Yep - you pass in the name of the prefix as the value to be true, so you would set `'admin'=>true` in your case.

Comment: I am using same link for both admin and manager.. so if I give like this  $this->Html->link(__('Products'), array('controller' => 'products','action'  => index','manager'=>true,'admin'=>true)); is correct ?

Comment: You need to know what the current prefix is. The only way i can see of doing this automatically is with the Router class. See edited answer.